# Javascript property thunk

Tags: javascript, dom, cookies

I want to override the DOM document object's 'cookie' property with a hook. Basically I want to capture all calls by any script to the document.cookie object's getter or setter. In the setter I want to trace out the call and then call the original setter. In the getter I just want to log the call (actually I don't really need to override the getter). I have figured out how to override the document.cookie property. See code below. It does write a trace any time document.cookie's getter or setter is called. But, because I don't call the original setter on document.cookie the page doesn't work correctly. What I can't figure out is how to retain a pointer to the original setter so I can call it from my override setter. Thought I would cast the question out to the community and see if anyone has any suggestions. Doesn't need to work in a wide browser matrix either. Just Chrome desktop latest would be fine.

Thank you!

Mike

P.S. Example what I have so far

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(document);
Object.defineProperty(proto, 'cookie', {
    get: function() {
        console.log('cookie getter');
    },
    set: function(val) {
        console.log('cookie setter ' + val);
        console.trace();
    }
});

document.cookie = 'foo=bar';
var xxx = document.cookie;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This has been closed as a duplicate, as the answer there should solve your similar problem, but I just want to thank you for a well-written question.  You explained well what you wanted, showed code that got much of the way there and asked how to jump one more hurdle.  I wish more questions were like this.